# Server returns status 403 forbidden when i send request with bearer token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm working with security and have a task which is bind to jwt. When i received jwt and have already saved it in LocalStorage, i was trying to send requests to the server and put this jwt in headers: Authorization: "bearer " + jwt, but server only returned status 403 forbidden. I thought, that the reason is in requests that sending earlier then token was put in header, but i've tried to put this token artificially and server also returned 403, in postman everything works well

this is my axios instance

```
 const TOKEN_STRING = localStorage.getItem("jwt") || ""
    
    export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + TOKEN_STRING,
      },
    })
```

thats how i save token in the login page

```
 const submit = async () => {
    try {
      await axios
        .post(baseUrl + "/api/login", loginData)
        .then((res) => localStorage.setItem("jwt", res.data.jwt))
    } catch (e) {
      setError(e.message)
    }
  }
```

and this how i send request, which is after login page so as i think should be after localStorage receives token

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance
        .get(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_BACKEND_URL + "/api/discounts")
        .then((response) =>
          setDiscounts(() =>
            response.data.map((el, index) => ({
              ...el,
              img: cardImages[index],
            }))
          )
        )
    } catch (e) {
      setDiscountsFetchError(e.message)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

i think it's enough for example but if smbd needs more info i'll give

Comment: 403 forbidden usually means, that eventhough the request could be authenticated with a valid user, the authenticated user is not allowed to access that resource. If the user could not be authenticated, the server usually responds with 401 unauthorized.

Comment: But why with the same token  it works in postman?

Comment: Furthermore, do you create your `axiosInstance` before or after the login?

Comment: after login, login page uses common axios

Comment: Check the request in the developer tools of the browser if it contains the correct token. Also please show the working request in Postman (for instance as a cURL export)

Comment: You could also set a breakpoint on `axios.create` to check if it got the correct token from the localStorage

Comment: And to be honest `export const axiosInstance = axios.create({ ... ` looks more like this code is executed at startup and not only after you sucessfully logged in ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you creating the axios instance way before your login call so the jwt is empty at that time.

Try the following in your fetch data request after login call, when jwt is present in local storage.

```
axiosInstance
.get(
process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_BACKEND_URL + "/api/discounts", 
{
 headers: {
   Accept: "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
   Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
 }
})
```

Comment: Can you take the cURL and check the validity of the token on postman as mentioned in derpirscher's comment